# clang to create output directory

Tags: c, clang

I want *clang* to create a new directory for output files.

For example:

```
/usr/bin/clang -std=gnu17 -g /path/to/file/test2.c -o /path/to/file/build
```

Obviously, I keep getting *errno=2 (no such file or directory)*:

```
ld: can't open output file for writing: /path/to/file/build, errno=2 for architecture x86_64
```

Is there any way to force a compiler to create a new directory for output files?

Comment: No there isn't. It's up to you to create the directory first.

Comment: ok @kaylum, thanks. Just wanted to add .build/ to .gitignore file but need to find another way. cheers

Comment: What does gitignore have to do with getting the compiler to create the directory? Regardless of who creates the directory it still needs to be added to gitignore if indeed you want to ignore it. Perhaps if you asked about the underlying problem someone may be able to help with that.

Comment: start to use cmake or make

Comment: I wanted to add to .gitignore compiled file basename with no extension (my binary files), so thought that maybe creating *build* directory for output and adding to .gitignore will be simpler solution. anyway I've already found the solution - ignore all files and then unignore all dirs and files with specific extensions.

Comment: That is not a universal solution. For example .c files and .h files can be generated by parser generators, yet the generated files would not necessarily need to be in git.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you want to use clang itself for creating the directory

but there are other ways

you can use `mkdir` before you use clang
like that

```
mkdir path/yourfolder | /usr/bin/clang -std=gnu17 -g /path/to/file/test2.c -o /path/to/file/build
```